# From multiple maps and a list of keys TO list of keys and corresponding values from maps

Tags: collections, clojure

Input:

```
List of keys: [ :name :address :work]
Map 1: { :name "A" :address "A Street" }
Map 2: { :work "Work Ave" }
```

Output:

```
([:name "A" nil] [:address "A Street" nil] [:work nil "Work Ave"])
```

This is what I have at the moment:

```
(defn maps-iterate [v & ms]
    (map (fn [k] (into [] [k #(map (k %) ms)])) v))

(println (maps-iterate [ :name :address :work ] { :name "A" :address "A Street"} { :work "Work Ave" }))
```

Which gives me:

```
([:name #<user$maps_iterate$fn__2$fn__3 user$maps_iterate$fn__2$fn__3@4b14b82b>] 
 [:address #<user$maps_iterate$fn__2$fn__3 user$maps_iterate$fn__2$fn__3@3d47358f>] 
 [:work #<user$maps_iterate$fn__2$fn__3 user$maps_iterate$fn__2$fn__3@e0d5eb7>])
```

Comment: Why do you want nil values in your output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
(defn maps-iterate [v & ms]
    (map (fn [k] (into [] [k (map #(k %) ms)])) v))
```

Or even better:

```
(defn maps-iterate [v & ms]
    (map (fn [k] (cons k (map k ms))) v))
```

Note: if all keys are keywords, then you can use them as functions: `(map k ms)` instead of `(map #(k %) ms)`. If they are not then you can't use them as functions. You need to write `(map #(% k) ms)`

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
(for [k ks]
  [k (map k [m1 m2])])
;;=> ([:name ("A" nil)] [:address ("A Street" nil)] [:work (nil "Work Ave")])
```

or, if you really want a flat vector in the results:

```
(for [k ks]
  (apply vector k 
         (map k [m1 m2])))
;;=> ([:name "A" nil] [:address "A Street" nil] [:work nil "Work Ave"])
```

Comment: Why don't use `(map k [m1 m2])` instead of `(for [m [m1 m2]] (k m))`?

Answer (score 1):

```
user=> (def a { :name "A" :address "A Street" })
#'user/a
user=> (def b { :work "Work Ave" })
#'user/b
user=> (def c [ :name :address :work])
#'user/c
user=> (map #(vector %1 (%1 a) (%1 b)) c)
([:name "A" nil] [:address "A Street" nil] [:work nil "Work Ave"])
```

Answer (score -1):

The following REPL example produces your output without the nil values indicated:

```
user> (def map1 { :name "A" :address "A Street" })
#'user/map1
user> (def map2 { :work "Work Ave" })
#'user/map2
user> (seq (merge map1 map2))
([:work "Work Ave"] [:name "A"] [:address "A Street"])
```